# Masking a DataFrame using multiple criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know one can mask out certain rows in a data frame using e.g.

```
(1) mask = df['A']=='a'
```

where *df* is the data frame at hand having a column named *'A'*. Calling *df[mask]* yields my new "masked" DataFrame.

One can of course also use multiple criteria with

```
(2) mask = (df['A']=='a') | (df['A']=='b')
```

This last step however can get a bit tedious when there are several criteria that need to be fulfilled, e.g.

```
(3) mask = (df['A']=='a') | (df['A']=='b') | (df['A']=='c') | (df['A']=='d') | ...
```

Now, say I have my filtering criteria in an array as

```
(4) filter = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', ...]
    # ... here means a lot of other criteria
```

Is there a way to get the same result as in (3) above, using a one-liner?

Something like:

```
(5) mask = df.where(df['A']==filter)
    df_new = df[mask]
```

In this case (5) obviously returns an error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use [`Series.isin()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
filter = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
df_new = df[df["A"].isin(filter)]
```

`df_new` is a DataFrame with rows in which the entry of `df["A"]` appears in `filter`.

Comment: Thanks @ajcr, I did not know about that function. Very neat indeed!

Comment: No problem! It's one of the `Series` methods I've really come to depend on.